# Issue with namespaces in XSLT Translation

Tags: xml, xslt

*I found out that the issue seems to be because of the line

xmlns="http://sample.com/task/1.0"

There was no namespace assigned and when I added one (ns1) things seemed to translate the way I wanted to. My revised question would be "Why was not having a namespace assigned there a problem, and if I were to want to change that in many files, how would I do that?"

I am new to XSLT but am trying to take an XML document and turn it into RDF. My approach was to just start with a simple translation to pull out some XML terms in plain text to start off. I took an XML file, stripped it of namespaces, and was able to get things to display properly.

In this iteration, I added the namespaces back to the XML file, but kept them from being referenced in tags. I also added them to the XSL file. When I run the translation, I only get the text that I wrote before the values. However, when I change the xsl:template match to be anything beyond "/*", I get the values but not the text. Here is the code

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<getCollectiveTaskResponse xmlns="http://sample.com/task/1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://sample.com/commonElements/1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://sample.com/individualTask/1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://sample.com/collectiveTask/1.0" xmlns:ns5="http://sample.com/xsd/handle" xmlns:ns6="http://sample.com/appinfo/1">
<collectiveTask>
    <generalInformation>
        <number>13</number>
        <title>Quarterback</title>
        <name>Dan Marino</name>
    </generalInformation>    </collectiveTask>
```

And here is the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://sample.com/task/1.0"     xmlns:ns2="http://sample.com/commonElements/1.0"     xmlns:ns3="http://sample.com/individualTask/1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://sample.com/collectiveTask/1.0" xmlns:ns5="http://sample.com/xsd/handle" xmlns:ns6="http://sample.com/appinfo/1">
<xsl:template match="/getCollectiveTaskResponse">



Number:<xsl:value-of select="collectiveTask/generalInformation/number"/>
Title:<xsl:value-of select="collectiveTask/generalInformation/title"/>
Name:<xsl:value-of select="collectiveTask/generalInformation/name"/>

</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor then to make your template

```
<xsl:template match="/getCollectiveTaskResponse">



Number:<xsl:value-of select="collectiveTask/generalInformation/number"/>
Title:<xsl:value-of select="collectiveTask/generalInformation/title"/>
Name:<xsl:value-of select="collectiveTask/generalInformation/name"/>

</xsl:template>
```

work you need to put `xpath-default-namespace="http://sample.com/task/1.0"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element.